# NSMutableString:rangeOfString: weird NSRange result

Tags: objective-c

Trying to figure out why NSMutableString:rangeOfString: is returning really weird results. NSLog is showing me a result like this:

location=9223372036854775807 length=0:This is a test

My test string does not contain "@@@", so I'd expect location=0 length=0. The weird location keeps coming up until the string actually contains "@@@" then location and length are correct. What am I missing in the below code snippet?

ServerPacketMotd.h

```
typedef struct _serverPacketMotdStruct
{
    int8_t  type;           /* SP_MOTD */
    int8_t  pad1;
    int8_t  pad2;
    int8_t  pad3;
    int8_t  line[80];
} serverPacketMotdStruct;
```

ServerPacketMotd.m

```
#import "ServerPacketMotd.h"

@interface ServerPacketMotd()
{
    NSMutableString *buffer;
}
@end

@implementation ServerPacketMotd

- (id)init
{
    if( !( self = [super init] ) )
        return nil;

    buffer = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    return self;
}

- (NSMutableData *)handlePacket:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    serverPacketMotdStruct gamePacket;
    uint16_t size = sizeof(serverPacketMotdStruct);
    NSRange packetWindow = NSMakeRange(0, size);
    NSRange atAtAt = NSMakeRange(0,0);

    while (expression)
    {
        [data getBytes:&gamePacket range:packetWindow];
        [buffer appendFormat:@"%s\n", gamePacket.line];

        atAtAt = [buffer rangeOfString:@"@@@"];
        NSLog(@"XXX location=%lu length=%lu:%@", atAtAt.location, atAtAt.length, buffer);
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `{0, 0}`?  The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) says:  Returns `{NSNotFound, 0}` if `aString` is not found or is empty (`@""`).

Comment: When you see what you think is a weird number try looking at its hex value as it might follow a pattern. In this case you have 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, which doesn't look very random so you have a clue... and a short while later you discover `NSNotFound`

Answer (score 4):

Check if `atAtAt.location == NSNotFound`. A location of `0` means the string was found at location 0, it doesn't mean it wan't found.